# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I've downloaded the iso for ubuntu, put it on a bootable usb stick, installed ubuntu alongside windows 7 (allocating disk space during the installation, taking it from the hdd on which my windows 7 is installed). Installation worked fine but after rebooting it always starts up windows 7. no bootloader menu is shown during booting and inspecting the boot devices in my bios only lists the hdd that should now contain win7 & ubuntu.

What do I need to do in order to boot ubuntu/display the bootloader menu when i turn my computer on?

Comment: do  you use UEFI?

Comment: sorry, i dont know what that is. so i guess the answer might be "no"

Comment: if your pc is less than a few years old, the answer is probably "yes". If you use UEFI, there should be some EFI partition on your disk and your "Bios" is actually a "UEFI", so the term should appear somewhere in there.

Comment: 1. Sorry but how do i figure out whether or not I'm using UEFI?
2. How will that help me fix my boot problem?

Comment: for "how to find out", I tried to give you hints in my last comment. how old is your pc?
I ask because I had some issues with UEFI on my notebook.

Comment: Thx for trying to help and sorry for wasting your time. I've fixed it by using Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 1):

Following this answer fixed it for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/156956/422210

(install Boot-Repair and press "Recommended Repair"